# Is this prove valid: $f$ is injective $\iff f(x) = cx$? (See below)

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Suppose the $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the following properties hold:

1. $f$ is everywhere continuous
2. $f(x+1) = f(x) + f(1)$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
3. $f(1) \ne 0$ (equivalently, $f(1) = c \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$)
4. $f(m) = cm$, for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ (not required because this property can be proved with 2 and 3)

Then, prove the following:

> $f$ is injective iff $f(x) = cx$, for some $c \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$

Here is my proof:

**Proof:**

#### $\Longleftarrow$

Suppose $f(x) = cx$, with $c \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$. Clearly $f(x) = cx$ is injective because, since $c \ne 0$:
$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(x_1) = f(x_2) &\iff cx_1 = cx_2\\
&\iff x_1 = x_2
\end{split}
\end{equation*}$$

Also:

- $f(1) = c \cdot 1 = c$
- $f(x+1) = c(x+1) = cx + c = f(x) + f(1)$
- $f$ is continuous

#### $\Longrightarrow$

We also write $f$ another way:

Define $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

- $g(x + 1) = g(x)$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
- $g(0) = 0$

Therefore, one can show that $f(x) = g(x) + cx$ satisfy all properties given for $f$.

**Claim:** $g$ is everywhere continuous.

*Proof:* Since $f$ and $cx$ is continuous everywhere, then $g(x) = f(x) - cx$ is also continuous everywhere. (END OF CLAIM) Q.E.D.

Now, since $f(x)$ is injective (by assumptiom), then let $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be its left inverse. So, suppose $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
x_1 = x_2 &\iff h(f(x_1)) =  h(f(x_2))\\
&\iff f(x_1) = f(x_2)\\
&\iff g(x_1) + cx_1 = g(x_2) + cx_2\\
&\iff g(x_1) - g(x_2) = c(x_2-x_1) = 0\\
&\iff g(x_1) = g(x_2)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}$$

and this is true for all, $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, $g(x) = 0$, for all real numbers $x$.
$$\therefore f(x) = cx, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Q.E.D.

## Question

Is this prove valid?

Comment: The claim is false, see for instance $g(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor + \{x\}^2$, where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor=x-\{x\}$.

Comment: You can make counterexamples that are $C^\infty$.

Comment: Incidentally, property 4 follows from property 2, alone. No need to invoke property 3.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio, but, $g(2.5) = \lfloor 2.5 \rfloor + {2.5}^2 = 2+0.25 = 2.25$, but $g(2.5 +1) = g(3.5) = 3 + 0.25 =  3.25 \ne g(2.5)$.

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz Yes, of course, because $g(2.5+1)=3.25=g(2.5)+g(1)$, just like you asked.

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz, Sassatelli is saying that his function $g$ has all the properties of $f,$ and is also injective, but is not a linear function at all.

Comment: Ohhh. Alright, my bad! Thank you!

Comment: Also, something has gone wrong when your proof somehow indicates to you that $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R,$ and also that $x_1=x_2$ if and only if $g(x_1)=g(x_2).$

Comment: I'm upvoting because this question showed clear effort.